# Nested SQL statement with AVG()

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have three tables I want to pull data from. One is a classes table that stores a list of classes offered including an id, time stamp, trainer id, start time, am/pm and the days a class is held.  The trainer id is a foreign key that ties it to a trainers table where i am pulling the trainer name based on the trainer's unique id.

That works fine, but I also need to display the average attendance of every class.  This involves a stats table that has a class id foreign key that puts the class id into a row along with the number of participants for that session. I want to return the average number of participants per class session for each class.

Below is my select statement:

```
SELECT 
                        class_id AS id, 
                        class_name, 
                        class_trainerid,
                        class_starttime AS start, 
                        class_ampm AS ampm,
                        class_days AS days,
                        trainer_id AS trainid,
                        trainer_name,
                        stat_class AS sclass,
                        AVG(stat_students) as stat_students_avg
                    FROM 
                        $class_table
                        LEFT JOIN $trainer_table ON (class_trainerid = trainer_id)
                        LEFT JOIN stats ON (id = stat_students_avg)
                    GROUP BY
                        id
```

The above code probably reveals that I don't actually have much of an idea how to do this. I have seen posts on averaging through joins, or using select statements within select statements, but I cannot seem to translate those to my question.

EDIT:
Here is the classes table schema:

```
`class_id` tinyint(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`class_datereated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`class_name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`class_trainerid` tinyint(8) NOT NULL,
`class_starttime` time NOT NULL,
`class_ampm` text NOT NULL,
`class_days` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`class_id`)
```

Here is the Trainer schema

```
`trainer_id` tinyint(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'trainer_datecreated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`trainer_name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`trainer_password` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`trainer_email` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`trainer_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`trainer_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`trainer_email`)
```

and here is the stats table schema:

```
`stat_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`stat_datecreated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`stat_class` int(8) NOT NULL,
`stat_students` int(8) NOT NULL,
`stat_trainer` tinyint(8) NOT NULL,
`stat_class_date` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`stat_id`)
```

The output would be part of a php while statement, that results in this:

```
echo "<table class='list'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Class Name</th><th>Trainer</th><th>Ave</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($class_result))
        {
            echo "<tr id='class_".$row["id"]."'>"; 
            echo "<td>".$row["class_name"]."</td>";
            echo "<td class='trainer-name'>".$row["trainer_name"]."</td>";
            echo "<td class='trainer-name'>".$row["stat_students_avg"]."</td>";
            echo "<td class='icon'><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='class_edit_".$row["id"]."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a></td>";
            echo "<td class='icon'><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='class_delete_".$row["id"]."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Can you post the table schema along with the expected output

Comment: Ok, I added the schemas and the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ON (id = stat_students_avg)` does not correspond the same value .

The only way that stat table can be joined to the class table is the **class_trainerid** of the class table and **trainer_id** of the stat table

You could try something like this

```
SELECT 
    class_id ,
    class_name,
    class_trainerid,
    class_starttime as start,
    class_ampm as ampm,
    class_days as days,
    trainer_id as trainid,
    trainer_name,
    stat_class as sclass,
    AVG(stat_students) as stat_students_avg
FROM
    $class_table

     LEFT JOIN $trainer_table ON (class_trainerid = trainer_id)
      LEFT JOIN stats ON (trainer_id  = class_trainerid)
GROUP BY
      class_id
```

Comment: That actually fixed a lot, but I get the same number for all the class entries. Would I need to do a select within a select to pull the average for each class id?

Comment: actually you can create a new query for avg only based on class_id

Comment: How woudl that work within the while loop of the previous query?

Comment: create a  function for that will return the AVG and the needed parameter is the class id 

`function getAvgByClassId($id){
    //your query here for avg where class_id = '$id'
    // then return the result
}`

Inside your while loop you can use the function and pass the class id
sample
` echo getAvgByClassId($row["class_id "]);`